# Filtering executable files in QFileDialog on Linux

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am trying to make a file picker to select a program (executable file).

My understanding of the documentation for QDir and QFileDialog is that the following should show a file dialog with only executable files. However, it shows no files at all (and no directories either) even though there are executable files in the directory.

```
    self.browseDialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
    self.browseDialog.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.Executable | QtCore.QDir.Files)
    self.browseDialog.exec_()
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can this be achieved? I would also like to do something a little more complex: show files that are executable *or* end with certain extensions.

I am using PyQt 4.7.4 on Ubuntu Maverick.

Comment: Did you try or-ing in QtCore.QDir.AllDirs?

Comment: Your example works fine for me and displays files. You can even remove the `Files` filter and just use `Executable`. Not sure why you are seeing different results.

Comment: @jdi, you **must** use the `Files` filter, too. The docs express this clearly: *The Executable value needs to be combined with Dirs or Files.*

Comment: But please be aware that if you're using one of the static methods (like `getOpenFileName()`), you must pass your filter as a string, and **not** as a flag.

Answer (score 0):

I am using PyQt5 but had to do a similar thing only I wanted just .txt files. To perform this I used getFileOpenName() and the filter= option. It worked fine for my purposes. The function names have changed from PyQt4 to PyQt5, but the link below has the names of the PyQt4 alternatives.

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html

> The getOpenFileNameAndFilter(), getOpenFileNamesAndFilter() and
>   getSaveFileNameAndFilter() methods of PyQt4’s QFileDialog have now
>   been renamed getOpenFileName(), getOpenFileNames() and
>   getSaveFileName() respectively in PyQt5. PyQt4’s implementations of
>   getOpenFileName(), getOpenFileNames() and getSaveFileName() are not
>   supported in PyQt5.